# Programs running in background mac

Tags: macos, daemons, activity-monitor

I suspect my Macbook Pro has been hacked by sophisticated hackers who may have even customized some special malware for my computer.  Is there anyway to tell from looking at the MacBook Pro Activity Monitor like spotting hidden files and other potential unknown processes.  What can I do above and beyond installing an anti-virus program to identify if someone is hacking the computer?  Energy usage and server traffic statistics..?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: I see the down votes, but please realize that I am not able to add an image to my question so it is hard for me to describe.

Comment: you can host the image and provide a link in your question

Comment: You can use little snitch to control your internet access [output - input].